# Besides BSD and Linux, are there any other open-source Unix descendants currently in development?

Tags: linux, unix, bsd

This week I'm going to install every major BSD and Linux distro and learn for myself how they differ. Are there any other Unix open-source projects besides these two ancestors that I should consider analyzing?

Comment: Note, we have also a https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: "Currently in development" conflicts with "ancestors".

Comment: @peterh I thought superuser was the place for unix stuff, my bad. Too many SE subsites.

Comment: @alanwaring Not surely, many SE sites are not very, well... "welcoming". If there are many, there are more options to find alternatives inside the network. Btw, having the "unix" name in it will likely attract real unix gurus (and security SE attracts security experts, or physics SE is full with physics Phds). Thus, it elevates the mean level of skill in the given topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Illumos (descendant of Solaris, System V)
- Minix

Comment: I think your post qualifies as an acceptable answer ("Looks OK"), but it would be much better if you would extend it with some elaboration & links.

Comment: The newest version of Minix I've been able to find is 3.4.0rc6 from 2016.  So I wouldn't consider that to be "currently in development".